# Blazor Server CSS Isolation + TailwindCSS build

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make TailwindCSS CLI to also include the CSS from my CSS-isolated blazor components.

Here is my `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"

<h1 class="index-H1">Hello, world!</h1>

<span class="from-iso">Welcome to your new app.</span>
```

And here is its `Index.razor.css`

```
.from-iso {
    @apply text-blue-600;
}
```

now this is my `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./Shared/*.{html,razor,cshtml,css}",
        "./Pages/*.{html,razor,cshtml,css}"
    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Everytime I make changes to `Index.razor.css`, the custom classes I added doesn't appear in the output css file (in this case, the `.from-iso` class). Am I missing something?